# How to disable TRUNCATE on whole database or for particular table?

Tags: postgresql, truncate

Is it possible to disable TRUNCATE operation on the entire PostgreSQL database, or on a specific table?

Comment: TRUNCATE is mentioned on this page [REVOKE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-revoke.html) about "remove access privileges", so i guess that is possible.

Comment: Perfect, thank you.

Comment: @Artegon: but you can't revoke that privilege from the table owner.

Comment: Which is (one of the many reasons) why apps should never login as the table owner.